# GitHub ActionsによるRSpecテストで発生する「undefined method `now' for nil:NilClass」エラーを解決したい。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, rspec, github-actions

現在、バック（Rails API）とフロント(react)を分けてSPA開発を行っており、下記がディレクトリ構成になります。

**ディレクトリ構成**

```
.
|- api(docker)
|  |- .github/workflows/github-action.yml
|  |- config/database.yml.ci
|  |- Gemfile
|  |- Gemfile.lock
|  |- Dockerfile
|
|- front(docker)
|  |- Dockerfile
|
|- .gitmodules（api/frontはサブモジュールで管理）
|- docker-compose.yml
```

今回、GitHub Actionsを使用して自動テストの実装を進める中で下記エラーに遭遇した次第です。

**エラー内容**

```
Failures:

  1) Comments API POST /api/v1/travel_records/:travel_record_id/comments コメントが正しく入力されている場合 コメントが作成できること
     Failure/Error:
       post api_v1_travel_record_comments_path(travel_record1.id),
            params: { user_id: user1.id, content: 'test_comment' }

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `now' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/requests/comments_spec.rb:11:in `block (5 levels) in <main>'
     # ./spec/requests/comments_spec.rb:10:in `block (4 levels) in <main>'

  2) Comments API POST /api/v1/travel_records/:travel_record_id/comments コメントが正しく入力されている場合 コメント通知レコードが作成されること
     Failure/Error:
       post api_v1_travel_record_comments_path(travel_record1.id),
            params: { user_id: user1.id, content: 'test_comment' }

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `now' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/requests/comments_spec.rb:19:in `block (5 levels) in <main>'
     # ./spec/requests/comments_spec.rb:18:in `block (4 levels) in <main>'
```

**原因**

- リクエスト時にエラー吐かれていることからフロント側の設定を記述する必要があるのではないかと考えております（モデルテストは成功しております）
  エラー内容をググってみたのですが参考記事を見つけることができず、現在も調査中です。
  解決方法について分かる方いらっしゃいましたらご教示いただけると幸いです。

**該当ファイル**

`.github/workflows/github-action.yml`

```
name: Run rspec

on:
  push:

jobs:
  rspec:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 10
    services:
      mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        ports:
          - 3306:3306
        env:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
        options: --health-cmd "mysqladmin ping" --health-interval 10s --health-timeout 5s --health-retries 10

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Ruby
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          bundler-cache: true

      - name: Cache node modules
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: node_modules
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-node-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-node-

      - name: Bundler and gem install
        run: |
          gem install bundler
          bundle install --jobs 4 --retry 3 --path vendor/bundle

      - name: Yarn install
        run: yarn install --check-files

      - name: Database create and migrate
        run: |
          cp config/database.yml.ci config/database.yml
          bundle exec rails db:create RAILS_ENV=test
          bundle exec ridgepole --apply -E test -f db/Schemafile -c config/database.yml.ci

      - name: Run rspec
        env:
          RAILS_ENV: test
          RAILS_MASTER_KEY: ${{ secrets.RAILS_MASTER_KEY }}
        run: bundle exec rspec
```

`config/database.yml.ci`

```
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8mb4
  username: root
  password: password
  host: 127.0.0.1
  database: app_test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しましたので共有いたします。

原因としてタイムゾーンが設定しておらず、エラーが吐かれておりました。
そのため、`env`に環境変数を設定することでエラーを解消することができました！

```
- name: Run rspec
  env:
    TZ: "Asia/Tokyo" // 追加
    RAILS_ENV: test
    RAILS_MASTER_KEY: ${{ secrets.RAILS_MASTER_KEY }}
  run: bundle exec rspec
```